# How to configure Kafka server with SASL_SSL and GSSAPI protocols

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kerberos, sasl, gssapi

I am **new to Apache Kafka**, and here is [**what I have done so far**](https://youtu.be/LGm5pV5lDDw),

1. Downloaded **kafka_2.12-2.1.0**
2. Make Batch file for **Zookeeper** to run zookeeper server:

   `start kafka_2.12-2.1.0.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat kafka_2.12-2.1.0.\config\zookeeper.properties`
3. Make Batch File for Apache Kafka server

   `start kafka_2.12-2.1.0\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat kafka_2.12-2.1.0\config\server.properties`
4. Started A Producer using batch file.

   `start kafka_2.12-2.1.0.\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic 3drocket-player`

It is running fine but now I am looking for **authentication**. As I have to implement a consumer with specific auth settings (requirement by the client). Like security protocol is **SASL_SSL** and *SSL mechanism* is **GSSAPI**. 
For this reason, I tried to search and find [confluet documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/sasl.html) but the problem is it is too abstract that how to take each and every step.

I am looking for detail configuration steps according to my setup. How to configure my kafka server with SASL SSL and GSSAPI protocol. Initially I found that GSSAPI/Keberos has a separate server then, do i need to install more server? Within Confluent Kafka is there any built-in solution.

Comment: GSSAPI is not an "_SSL mechanism_", its an abstraction layer over different authentication  mechanisms (Kerberos, NTLM) trying to coexist on some platforms. https://serverfault.com/questions/139896/what-is-sasl-gssapi

Comment: I found that SASL_SSL can be implemented through GSSAPI/Kerberoz

Answer (score 0):

Configure a SASL port in server.properties

e.g)

```
listeners=SASL_SSL://host.name:port
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=keystore_password
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=truststore_password
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_configbroker
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_config

Client:
When you run the Kafka client, you need to set these properties.

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=truststore_password
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
```

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_configclients
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_kerberos_clientconfig

Then configure the JAAS configuration

```
KafkaClient {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="path/to/kafka_client.keytab"
   storeKey=true
   useTicketCache=false
   principal="kafka-client-1@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

Comment: where is the kerberos server? and what is JAAS configuration?

Comment: If you want to use kerberized service, you need to set up the server. Please check this first. 
https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/install.html

JAAS is just a configuration file
https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html#jaas-configurations

Comment: You mean i have to setup a separate server for kerberos?

Answer (score 0):

...
SASL/GSSAPI is for organizations using Kerberos (for example, by using Active Directory). You don’t need to install a new server just for Apache Kafka®. Ask your Kerberos administrator for a principal for each Kafka broker in your cluster and for every operating system user that will access Kafka with Kerberos authentication (via clients and tools).
https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_gssapi.html#kafka-sasl-auth-gssapi
....

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)